# DynamicProxy as a Service is not found at runtime

Tags: wcf, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm trying to develop a WCF Service to be used as a Proxy of an already defined Web Service from a Provider.

Here is the steps that i followed to acomplish this goal:

1. Create a WCF Service Application
2. Added a Service reference to the Provider Web Service
3. Added `Global.asax` to the project.
4. Added `Castle.Core` (v3.2) reference via NuGet to the project.
5. Added some code to the Global.asax

Here is the code in my `Global.asax`

```
/// <summary>
/// Contiene eventos globales ejecutados 
/// </summary>
public class Global : HttpApplication
{

    private static readonly ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();

    private static List<object> proxies = new List<object>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Evento que se ejecuta cuando se inicializa la aplicacion
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Objeto que origna el evento</param>
    /// <param name="e">Argumentos del evento</param>
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConfigurarServicios();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Busca los servicios registrados en el proyecto
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Coleccion de servicios registrados y que extienden
    /// la clase ServiceBase</returns>
    private static IEnumerable<Type> BuscarServicios()
    {
        ConfigurarProxies();

        var list = new List<Type>();

        foreach (var proxy in proxies)
        {
            list.Add(proxy.GetType());
        }

        return list;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configura los servicios del proyecto para ser accedidos
    /// a traves de REST y SOAP
    /// </summary>
    private static void ConfigurarServicios()
    {
        var soapFactory = new ServiceHostFactory();

        var services = BuscarServicios();
        foreach (var serviceType in services)
        {
            string serviceName = "xm";

            var soapEndpoint = new ServiceRoute("Servicios/" + serviceName, soapFactory, serviceType);


            RouteTable.Routes.Add("Servicios/" + serviceName,soapEndpoint);

        }
    }

    private static void ConfigurarProxies()
    {
        var interceptor = new Interceptor(); 

        var proxy1 = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(typeof(ExternalServices.XpressMoney.XMSendTxnServicePortType), interceptor);


        proxies.Add(proxy1);
    }
}
```

When I run the project, everything just work fine, but when I try to access to the `ServiceRoute` /Servicios/xm, it shows me the next error:

```
The type 'Castle.Proxies.XMSendTxnServicePortTypeProxy, DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
```

And this is the stack:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The type 'Castle.Proxies.XMSendTxnServicePortTypeProxy, DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null', provided a the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.]
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +59318
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1434
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598


[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Servicios/xm' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'Castle.Proxies.XMSendTxnServicePortTypeProxy, DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +499812
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetRouteServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +6
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

I guess that the problem occurs when the .NET Framework try to dynamically instantiate the DynamicProxy, but I really don't know. Maybe the Next Lines is a clue:

```
var soapEndpoint = new ServiceRoute("Servicios/" + serviceName, soapFactory, serviceType);

RouteTable.Routes.Add("Servicios/" + serviceName,soapEndpoint);
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: "I'm trying to develop a WCF Service to be used as a Proxy of an already defined Web Service from a Provider." Any reason you are doing this at OSI Application layer? You could easily implement this on the transport layer or presentation layer. Heck there are even off the shelf components to do this from M$. Heck you could even run this at the WCF messaging layer (and avoid the overhead of the deserialization).

Comment: I need to do some logs before send the request to the service and some others after get the response.

Comment: In that case the message level is where you need to do your work. You don't need to use a service.

Comment: It's important to know that the system that needs the information has no access to the Internet, it only access to a DMZ where this service is supposed to be. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll talk with the "Network infrastructure team" about  that.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to use WebAPI to receive the request. Forward it to the actual service, and pipe the response straight to the client.